# Pass data between 2 classes using Observer/Event handlers

Tags: c#, windows, forms

Basically, I have a Windows Form, that has a control, in a control,in a control. Basically, I when something happens in the child control, I want the Parent/Top-most control to know.

I dont want to have to pass an instance of the parent control 2 levels deep. Also, using Observer/Event handlers seems to require an instance of the child class to be created to register for such events.

What on earth can I do here? Even Obj-C has global RegisterForNotifications.

Answer (score 2):

The controls shouldn't know who contains them. They should simply publish events others can subscribe to. So, your innermost child raises an event that the next-outer child subscribes to. It processes it, and may raise an event of its own, which another 'container' (control or the form) subscribes to, and so on. See this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973905.aspx